# Browserify produces an unusable bundle.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I'm trying to get a very simple React app to work. I want to `require()` React, so I'm using browserify to produce a bundle.js:

```
browserify -t babelify libs.js -o bundle.js
browserify -t reactify app.jsx -o app.js
```

When the page loads, it does not show the React content. On the console, it says: ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined

However, when I replace the `<script src="bundle.js">` with

```
<script src="js/react-0.14.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/react-dom-0.14.0.js"></script>
```

everything works.
I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. I'd appreciate hints as to what I'm doing wrong.

helloworld.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.jsx:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

libs.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.jsx should have the requires.

```js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```